# java support online certificate status protocol

Tags: java, security, cryptography, x509certificate, ocsp

I am looking into OCSP support in Java.
I see that there are some APIs offered in plain java for this(i.e. without using some third-party library e.g. Bouncy Castle).
Now I know, that OCSP can be implemented via `Direct Trust Model` and `Delegated Trust Model`.
From various posts I get the impression that the direct trust model is supported e.g I have seen something like:

```
X509Certificate  ocspCert = getCertFromFile(OCSP_SERVER_CERT);
certSet.add(ocspCert);
CertStoreParameters storeParams = new CollectionCertStoreParameters(certSet);
CertStore store = CertStore.getInstance("Collection", storeParams);
       // init PKIX parameters
PKIXParameters  params = null;
params = new PKIXParameters (trustedCertsSet);
params.addCertStore(store);
```

and as I understand the code, the OSCP server certificate is being passed to the framework for validation.
My question is the following: Is the `Delegated Trust Model` supported as well? If some example was provided, it would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

RedHat has an open source [OCSP Tools](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Certificate_System/7.1/html/Administrators_Guide/ocsp.html) written in Java.